# JOrbis can't read ogg file from JAR

Tags: java, audio, ogg

I want to play an .ogg file, so i found [this](http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/tutorial/ExamplePlayer.java) piece of code.
So it downloads .ogg file from the given url and plays it. I've tried it with external files like

`ExamplePlayer player = new ExamplePlayer(new File("D:\\sound.ogg").toURI().toURL().toString())`

and it works. But when i try this with internal files and get it using

`ExamplePlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sound.ogg")`

it says that "There is a hole in the first packet data.". I think maybe it doesn't work because of JAR's compression or something.

So questions are: why it doesn't work? how could i fix it? If i can't fix it, is there any other way to play .ogg files using java? Thanks.

UPD: I found a lib, but the problem still the same, it cannot read from jar file. It

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at an application I wrote several years ago that uses ogg resources, and seeing that I first import the ogg file to an `InputStream` object using `getResourceAsStream` method.

Usually with wav files, importing via the URL is preferred. Unfortunately I don't recall why I did it this way--too much new tech under the bridge. First guess is that it's a requirement from the *jcraft* code, otherwise I would have used my preferred method.

Even if this works in the context of an IDE, IDK if it will also work after putting the code into a JAR. `getResourceAsStream` is often dicey in jars.

Before I invest more time, please let us know if switching to `getResourceAsStream` does the trick. Maybe the fix is that simple!

+++++++++++++
EDIT: Ugh. Looking at my code, I see where I copied a class from *JCraft* and edited it, supplying an `InputStream` via wrapper code. The edit was made in order to output float PCM data from the decoder rather than having the decoder play the sound. The float PCM is then saved in a custom object similar to [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue), and the app I wrote this for uses that for playback. All I can remember was that it took a lot tweaking to get this to work.